# How do you position a core-overlay item?

Tags: polymer

The [documentation](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/elements/core-overlay.html#core-overlay.events.core-overlay-position) for core-overlay leaves a bit to be desired. Ideally, I want to use a core-overlay that positions itself on the screen *not* centered horizontally and vertically, but rather more like a dropdown menu.

I'm not using core-dropdown-menu due to other restrictions on the click-event handling on the menu itself (it needs to stay opened and have a resizeable menu div).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to position an overlay by adjusting its CSS at runtime.

```
overlay.style.position = 'absolute';
overlay.style.top = (input.offsetTop + input.clientHeight) + 'px';
overlay.style.width = input.offsetWidth + 'px';
overlay.open();
```

Variable `overlay` points to an overlay element. Variable `input` would point to an element underneath of which the overlay should appear.

This approached worked for me well in Polymer 0.5, but it is also applicable to Polymer 1.x. Please note that there is no overlay component per se in Polymer 1.x. Instead one should create a separate element with behaviour `Polymer.IronOverlayBehavior`.